# Firefox Live DOM

Tags: firefox, dom, live

Is it possible through a plugin or setting or something to allow Firefox to recognize the live DOM source code?

Basically, firebug or other similar tools can recognize elements on the page which Firefox does not.

I understand with these extensions I have the ability to see such changes made by javascript, but Firefox does not seem to fully recognize them.

**I'll try to clarify.**

If I load a page and view source (ctrl-U), I see what the server sent to Firefox, and what Firefox ostensibly recognizes as the source code of the page.  If in that source code, there is javascript which alters the DOM, and then I hit (ctrl-U) again, the code is not updated.

I am using a testing tool (iMacros firefox plugin) to automate functionality, but it does not recognize the updated DOM because Firefox does not.  Firebug and similar tools can recognize these "live" updates.  Does that help?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You want a plugin to show the live DOM, but you don't recognize firebug to be such a plugin?  How would this plugin manifest itself?

Comment: This smells like your testing tool is reading the source being handed to Firefox, and not its DOM. It might help if you specify the tool.

Comment: Is your question really - "why is my DOM not being updated".  Or is it "how do I get Firefox to show me the updated DOM when I hit Ctrl+U"?  Why aren't Firebug or the Web Developer toolbar not OK?

Comment: @David - I think you're exactly right.  So, is there a way to get firefox to pickup the live DOM?

Comment: Firefox **does**. It's iMacros you are having issues with (and I'm not familiar with that).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.chapter31.com/2006/12/04/viewing-ajax-generated-source-code/

You can try using the web-developer extension with a view-generated-source option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure I understand your question, but I think what you're getting at is the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) extension for FireFox, specifically its "View Generated Source" feature.

That will let you see the altered DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug gives u this ability:

for instance check the HTML tab when running a jquery ticker and see the dynamic changes live in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I have weird issues with either the console or the DOM inspector with firebug, I find restarting the browser and validating your code is the way forward.

That said, I'm not really following your question, the document that firebug shows is the same one in the firefox window...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not that you want firefox to show the current DOM when you hit CTRL+U, but that you want some automated testing tool to be able to test your web pages.

Perhaps you should use a testing tool that is suited to the job of testing rich web applications, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), for example, can do this.