# Any way to view exactly what's going in the HTML via Firebug with dynamic updates to input fields?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, firebug

I'm using [JavaScript](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) to customize radio buttons. I added labels for each of the buttons and when I click the labels, it seems to be updating the selected radio properly, but not when I click the radio button graphic. (only the background position changes)

Is there anyway I can make it so I can view the changes when to each of the radio button input elements in firebug when clicking on them?

If you'd like to see an example of what I'm talking about, go [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/example/), inspect one of the radio button elements and click on them and you'll see the code never changes (i.e. checked="checked").

Answer (score 1):

When you change the DOM via Javascript, you're changing the in-memory version. The source of the DOM is never modified by your Javascript.

See: [Firefox Live DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901570/firefox-live-dom).

Comment: Any ideas why I can see changes like class names, inline styles, etc. but not the "checked" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the element and select "Inspect Element" it will show you the HTML for this element in memory and will reflect changes to that as you interact with the page.

Also if you select the "Script" tab you can find your javascript and set break points to allow you to step through the script and debug any issues that may be occurring.

Comment: I tried inspecting both radio button elements, and I see the style changes occurring live in the DOM, but the default checkbox that I have set to checked="checked" never changes when toggling between both options. Shouldn't this attribute appear in the last radio button I selected? Any ideas why?

Comment: OK that is bizarre, now I see the behavior your talking about. I would think that the attribute would update, but perhaps that only defines the value that is initially checked and doesn't affect which input is currently selected. However, when you click the "DOM" tab in the window to the right of the source, you can see the "checked" property change from true to false or vice versa, as you interact with the control in real time.

Comment: Yeah -- as long as Firebug's been around, surely I'm not the first person to notice this, so I'm surprised this attribute cannot be seen. The DOM tab at least allows me to confirm what I was wondering, since I can't actually test if the input is being updated properly as I'm only working on the front-end.